# Catch a javascript exception in onError event (webkitspeech recognition)

Tags: javascript, exception, webkit, speech-recognition

Following the [code of the Webkit Speech Recognition](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html) (see the source), I would like to catch the error when starting (for example when you refuse the browser to use the microphone) to do something else.

The problem is... I don't know how to catch this king of error.

The final goal is to pass the error message to the object that try to start the Webkit Speech Recognition. So if you have another (good) solution to do this.

I have a relationship like that :

```
var anObject= {
    recognizer : Recognizer,

    listen : function() {
        try{
            this.recognizer.listen();
        } catch (error) {
            alert('I want to do something here with the error');
        }
    }
}


var Recognizer = {


    listen: function()
    {
        var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        // recognition config

        try{
            recognition.start();
        } catch (error) {
             alert(error);
             // I've also tried "throw error;" but we never pass in this catch 
        }

        recognition.onerror = function(event) {
            console.log(event.error); // this works

            throw event.error; // the "exception" is thrown 
        }

        // other functions
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, I don't know why. I got an "Uncaught exception" so the exception is thrown, but not caught.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your sample codes won't work because the onerror is called asynchronously, and not caught by your catch or conditional statement.

The context of the function called on error is the SpeechRecognition object, and not the one where you try to catch it... Your best bet would be to call the object that handles the error from within the onerror function.

This should work:

```
var Recognizer = {
    listen: function()
    {
        var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

        recognition.onerror = function(event) {
            anObject.catchError(event);
        }

        recognition.start();
    }   
}

var anObject= {
    recognizer : Recognizer,

    listen : function() {
        this.recognizer.listen();
    },

    catchError: function(event) {
      switch (event.error) {
        case 'network':
          console.log('network error');
          break;
        case 'not-allowed':
        case 'service-not-allowed':
          console.log('permission denied by user or browser');
          break;
      }
    }
}

anObject.listen();
```

There is no automatic way to detect the difference between user denying permission, the browser denying permission, or even a user without a microphone.

Check out the [annyang Speech Recognition library](https://github.com/TalAter/annyang) which uses some extra logic to figure out the different causes of errors. It also deals with all the other headaches around using speech recognition, bypasses potential bugs that can crash the browser, and makes using Speech Recognition much simpler: https://www.talater.com/annyang/

Comment: Thanks but actually you didn't change the code, did you? You have replaced some logic by a switch. This part works fine as I can detect the error. I've updated my question to specify the console.log in onError is working.
My problem is to pass the error to the parent object.

I have also updated my question to explain the kind of relationship I would like to have.

Comment: This is an issue with the asynchronous nature of your code, not speech recognition.
Your best bet would be to call a global object to handle your error from the recognition's error event. I will update the answer above with the code.

Comment: I think I can handle the error with the window.onError, but I'm not mistaken, ALL errors will be handled. It's not great (but if there is no solution, I'll try this one)